# Getting dimensions of plane object in 3ds max sdk

Tags: c++, 3dsmax

I am trying to get the length and width of a plane object using 3ds max sdk, but didn't find any API to get it. I tried using the GetValue API but it is not working with plane object.
Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Hi, could you post your current code that you need help with (or the important parts), makes it easier for us to help you because we can start with the code you supplied.

Comment: Hi, I tried to get the width and height from bounding box of currently selected plane using the following method. But not sure whether there are other ways to get width and height directly. 

`Box3 box; GetCOREInterface()->GetSelectionWorldBox(0,box);`